# element background image won't render

Tags: css, image, background, element

I'm trying to create a block quote like in the image below:

http://www.norrislakevillas.com/images/block-quote-sample.png

The quotation marks sit in the bottom right corner of a 50 X 45 px transparent PNG image with 10px of spacing on the top and left.

The element is rendering correctly with the exception of the background image, it just won't show up.

CSS Code:

```
#block_quote{
   float:left;
   width:400px;
   background:#f7f7f7;
   background-image:url(images/quote-top.png) left top no-repeat;
   margin:50px 0 100px 53px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#block_quote p{
   font:italic 14px segoe ui, arial, sans-serif;
   color:#5f5f5f;
   line-height:1.4em;
   margin:0;
   padding:20px 15px 20px 60px;
}
```

Any ideas why the image isn't rendering?

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: Your css file is in a folder called css so you have to put ../images/quote-top.png in order to access the image file through your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Your image path needs to be relative to the CSS file. Also it's just background, not background-image if your using all the declarations in one line and the order at the end is `no-repeat top left`.

> background: url(images/quote-top.png) no-repeat top left;

Answer (score 0):

`background` is a "shorthand property" that sets all background properties, including the url of the image. The way you write it, it does not specify an image, only a color.

So don't mix up `background` and the individual background properties like `background-image`. It should be *either*

```
background:#f7f7f7 url(images/quote-top.png) no-repeat left top;
```

*or*

```
background-color:#f7f7f7;
background-image:url(images/quote-top.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left top;
```

but not any mix of these; that will confuse the browser.